# Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 localized Application Tile Title when use WNS notification service (New Live Tiles)

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

I have a Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 project, and I have localized application title with AppResLib project from Microsoft ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967550(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967550%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)) until here all ok.

But I needed to add a background task to update my live tile, because of this I changed the "Notification Service" to WNS, ok,not problem here, all working great.

Unfortunately, now my app gets the "Display Name" for Application Tile Title from the new Package.manifiest and "@AppResLib.dll,-100" is not working anymore. Note that the title of the app continues localized.

The new way to localized the Application Tile Title App neither is working, on a Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 I can not add a .resw resource files to get this work: ms-resource:ApplicationTitle.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It's broken in WP8.1 (see details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn642084(v=vs.105).aspx)

> **Localized tiles unsupported with Windows Notification Service**
>
> If your Windows Phone 8 app uses resource files to provide localized text for tiles, described in How to build a localized app for Windows Phone 8, your tiles will continue to function properly when you upgrade to Silverlight 8.1 as long as you continue to use the Microsoft Push Notification Service framework for your app’s push notifications. This is the default behavior when upgrading. If you choose instead to move to the Windows Notification Service, which is used by all Windows Phone Store apps, the localized text will be inaccessible and will not be displayed on your tiles. For information about choosing the push notification service for your app, see Choosing MPNS or WNS for a Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 app.